# Angular UpgradeModule, how to write a wrapper around an un-upgradable directive

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

I'm upgrading an AngularJS application to Angular 5, and if overall the hybrid setup is working fine, I'm looking for a solution to wrap directives that are using compile function or anything that prevent the upgrade (as explained in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15102). 
In it's anwser https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15102#issuecomment-286190833, gkalpak says

`3. Create your own (upgradeable) wrapper directive that acts as a proxy between the non-upgradeable AngularJS directive and Angular.`

Thing is, I wasn't able to find anything on how to do it, and more specifically about how to retrieve the directive using `$injector` inside my wrapper.

For example, the following directive:

```
angular.module('xyz').directive('tooltip', ['some.provider', function (popup) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            [...]
        }
    };
}]);
```

that would be used as `<div tooltip='some text'></div>`
can't be imported by the usual way thought the UpgradeModule:

```
@Directive({selector: '[tooltip]'})
export class TootlipDirective extends UpgradeComponent {

    @Input('tooltip') text: string;

    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
        super('tooltip', elementRef, injector);
    }
}
```

as it will fail with `Error: Upgraded directive 'tooltip' contains unsupported feature: 'compile'`.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit:
Okay, so according to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4891 it's just not possible to upgrade a simple directive without template.
Still, I made some progress with some introspection of `node_modules/@angular/upgrade/esm5/static.js`, it's using `injector.get('$injector').get(name + 'Directive')` to get the angularjs directive. So using this, I can inject my original directive and manipulate it inside my angular directive:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2,  injector: Injector, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) {
    //retrieve angularjs directive 
    this.directives = injector.get('$injector').get('tooltipDirective');
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.directives[0].compile(this.el.nativeElement);
}
```

That's probably the dirtiest hack I ever wrote... And it doesn't really help anyway.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: @Noki i've added an example but my question is more about how to use $injector to retrieve `tooltip` directive (in angularjs), and then use it in a @Directive used as a wrapper.